# Query dataframe for key words and return matching rows

Tags: regex, pandas, performance, dataframe, match

I have the following dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'Code': ['XAW', 'PAK', 'I', 'QP', 'TOPZ', 'XAW', 'APOL'],
    'Name': ['George Truck', 'Fred Williams', 'Jessica Weir', 'Tony P.', 'John Truck', 'Liz Moama', 'Emily Truck'],
    'Color': ['Blue', 'Green', 'Green', 'Red', 'Pink', 'Blue', 'Pink']
})


    Code    Name           Color
0   XAW     George Truck   Blue
1   PAK     Fred Williams  Green
2   I       Jessica Weir   Green
3   QP      Tony P.        Red
4   TOPZ    John Truck     Pink
5   XAW     Liz Moama      Blue
6   APOL    Emily Truck    Pink
```

Given a keyword, such as 'blue', I would like to retrieve the following rows:

```
0   XAW     George Paul    Blue
5   XAW     Liz Moama      Blue
```

The search can contain multiple keywords, for example, 'truck pink' would return:

```
4   TOPZ    John Truck     Pink
6   APOL    Emily Truck    Pink
```

Imagine that this dataframe has half a million rows and a few extra columns. Is there a fast way I can query the entire dataframe for specific keywords?

Comment: Why not concatenate the columns you want to look at and then just do `Series.str.contains`?

Comment: @ifly6 I might want to query for say just code APOL and not include rows that contain names where APOL is a substring. Perhaps some fancy regex would do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select by partial string from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/select-by-partial-string-from-a-pandas-dataframe) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181187/finding-string-over-multiple-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: If you don't care about substrings you could look at word boundaries: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html#wordboundary
\bgeorge\b.+\bblue\b -> matches line 0

Answer (score 1):

With search string `s = 'truck pink'`, set up a search column:

```
t = (df['Name'] + ' ' + df['Color']).str.lower()
```

I force everything to lower case, because your search example doesn't seem to be case-sensitive. If you have dynamic search inputs, also force the search field to lower case. Then do searches for contains like so:

```
d = {}
for i in s.split(' '):
    d[i] = t.str.contains(i, na=False)
```

I pass `na=False` because otherwise, Pandas will fill `NA` in cases where the string column is itself `NA`. We don't want that behaviour. The complexity of the operation increases rapidly with the number of search terms. Also consider changing this function if you want to match whole words, because `contains` matches sub-strings.

Regardless, take results and reduce them with bit-wise 'and'. You need two imports:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

df[reduce(and_, d.values())]
```

And thus:

```
   Code         Name Color
4  TOPZ   John Truck  Pink
6  APOL  Emily Truck  Pink
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine .str.contains with another method that takes for example s = 'trk' and returns all rows with 'truck' in them, i.e. a partial match?

Comment: You're looking for fuzzy matching, that's much more difficult (computationally intensive).